# iPhone - How can I detect a device is running an adhoc build of my app at runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ad-hoc-distribution

I want to use different API's when running adhoc deployments of my app compared to appstore deployments. Can this be found out at runtime?
I know I can use #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR and #if DEBUG when running from xcode but I want adhoc deployments to be detected as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Check that "../iTunesMetadata.plist" exists in your NSDocumentDirectory.

This file is present in app store builds only - and it's in the root of your application so it's safe for app store submission.

Comment: It appears to be present for ad-hoc builds as well. I'm using TestFlight; perhaps TestFlight adds the metadata in order to get pretty icons while downloading the app.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Preprocessor Macro  for your AdHoc configuration in Build Settings. #if ADHOC // do something

Comment: That will work but it fails the requirement of doing it at runtime :)

Comment: @Brett I don't know if one can programmatically find if app has been signed with AdHoc or Debug certificate. This may work - If you can read embedded.mobileprovision in your App bundle and look for your Provisioning profile name.

Comment: This is the right answer. Just change a variable if ADHOC defined and detect the variable value at runtime.